# Fish tank population modelling using differential equations

Tags: mathematical-modeling, differential

I have been given the basic differential equation for population modelling, which is
$$p'(t)=rp(t)\left(1-\frac{p(t)}k\right)$$. The coefficient $r$ is $10$ and constant $k$ is $500$, so  the carrying capacity is $500$ fish.
Each fish causes $5$ dollars of expenses per year, and the fish tank costs $1200$ dollars per year to operate. Each sold fish brings $15$ dollars of revenue.

I have been given the task of finding out the best way to harvest the fish without destroying the population and also with highest possible revenue. The assignment says that you can either harvest the fish certain fixed number evey year or harvest the fish based on the population with a certain multiplier.

Assuming that we use the constant amount $700$ and the multiplier $5$, we can get two different equations that model the fish population absed on two different strategies.

$$p'(t)= rp(t)\left(1-\frac{p(t)}k\right)-C$$ ($C$ being constant)

$$p'(t)=rp(t)\left(1-\frac{p(t)}k\right)-Bp(t)$$ ($B$ being a multiplier)

When we include the numerical values, we get:

$$p'(t)= 10p(t)\left(1-\frac{p(t)}{500}\right)-700\\
p'(t)=10p(t)\left(1-\frac{p(t)}{500}\right)-5p(t)$$

So far so good. But my problem is that how am I supposed to make a differential function that shows the rate of revenue?
My attempt was the following:

$$v'(t)=15 \cdot 700-5p(t)-1200\\
v'(t)= 15 \cdot p(t)-5p(t)-1200$$

My other attempt:

$$v'(t)= 15 \cdot 700t-5p(t)-1200t\\
v'(t)= 15 \cdot 5p(t)-5p(t)-1200t$$

I am making this with matlab, but the basic calculations are the thing that bugs me. Have I even done the first parts correctly? How can I form the revenue functions so that they are consistent? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Replacing $B, C$ with fixed values is counter to your purpose here. You need to find out which values of $B$ and $C$ maximize profit. You cannot do that if you've changed them out for particular values.

Comment: Your first attempt has what was probably a typo in the second equation (I did not change it when I converted to mathjax). You sell $5p(t)$ fish every year, not just $p(t)$..

Comment: Also, taking $C=700$ when the carrying capacity of the fish tank is $500$ would not work.

Comment: Same with $B=5$ actually, you are taking out $5$ times the population of the tank?

Comment: @Rem - note that the population of fish is increasing by 10 times each year (prolific little things). So you are going to need to remove a lot of fish to stay ahead of it. The proffered numbers are too low, not too high.

Comment: @PaulSinclair But this rate of ten is lowered by the term $(1-p/K)$? Furthermore, the $-C$ term leads to $p(t) = K/(1+Ae^{-10t}) - Ct$ which will dominate the increase with time no matter what.

Comment: @Rem - yes, that is part of what this exercise is about, and why it offers two strategies, not just one.

Comment: Good point. But then I was wondering, how would one model the "harvest a fixed amount every year"? Numerically, would a rule like "if $t=1 year, p(t) = p(t) - C$" instead of the $-C$ in the dynamics (which does not make sense to me) be appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

$v'(t) = \frac {dv}{dt}$ is how much $v(t)$ changes each year. I.e., it is how much profit you make in year $t$.

Consider the constant-sell strategy. In a given year, you sell $C$ fish. That brings in $15C$ in income. You spend $5p(t)$ on upkeep of the fish and $1200$ on upkeep of the tank.
So your profit is income less outgo:
$$v'(t) = (15C) - (5p(t) + 1200)$$

In your second attempt, you get the same result in year one, but in year $t = 2$, you are claiming to bring in $15C\cdot 2 = 30C$ in income, and $15C\cdot 3 = 45C$ in year $3$. Seems a pretty sweet deal, though the equally rising tank maintenance fees are taking a chunk out of it. At least the cost of feeding the fish isn't also rising each year.